# How can I find the volume of this prism and points B, C, D and F?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

In the triangular prism, A = (0, -1, 1), E = (0, -3, 0). C and D belong to line s: x - 1 = y = y - z. How can I find the prism's volume and the coordinates of B, C, D and F points?

[image]